# query to count the repeated participant names and display participant name only once with count

Tags: mysql

I have the following query,

```
SELECT Participant_name from Participant_email where Sub_id = 46
```

the result of this showing participant names in my table,in this table i have participant names repeated and i want to count each participant name how many times they are repeating.
like as :
mary (4)
hay (3)..

can any tell me how to write this query?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `COUNT()` which is an aggregate function and grouped them by their name.

```
SELECT Participant_name, COUNT(Participant_name) totalCount
from Participant_email 
-- where Sub_id = 46
GROUP BY Participant_name
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT CONCAT(Participant_name, ' (', COUNT(Participant_name), ')') Participant_name
from Participant_email 
-- where Sub_id = 46
GROUP BY Participant_name
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ca58/4)

Comment: how can i get these result in a single column

Comment: what do you mean by single column? results of all total participants?